# Css Keyframes Animation Pause

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Hey everyone I am working with @keyframes animations looks like this:

```
     @keyframes move{
       0%,
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, calc(100% + 45vmin), 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, calc(100% + 45vmin), 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, calc(100% + 45vmin), 0);
        }
    }
```

and the person that I am having test the animation is experiencing pausing in the chrome browser when they navigate to a new tab/window. Should this be happening? Could it be their computer or is this built into Chrome?

Also the animation is being added to the element via a class and jquery:

```
$('#element').addClass('move')
```

Comment: That sounds like a system restriction more than a problem with this code.

Comment: When are you adding the class?—if the class is on the element, the it should animate regardless.

Comment: @RooWM it is added after another animation ends. I am using the "animationend" event listener to track the ending.